# Foreach loop to export file to excel with different name everyday using windows task to run the schedule

Tags: powershell

I am extracting messages from the tenant server and exporting them into excel and that is working well for me. Since i dont want to manually run the script everyday, i used windows task to schedule the job which is also working well for me. But whenever the task runs each morning, it overrides the previous file created which is not good because, i want to have it create a new file with different name or at least put in a number in front of it to depict a different file. 
My test-path for my if statement is working well to check if the file is present or not but my foreach loop isn't. I want a new file to be created when the script is run with different name. I tried to use new-item to create a new file but i dont want to hard code the path because, my if statement is just going to tell me file exist again. Please help me.

```
$User = "ABC"
$PWord = cat Z:\mysecurestring.txt | convertto-securestring`
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord
$session = New-SCSession -Credential $credential -Locale en-US
if(Test-Path Z:\Schedule\MessageCenter.xlsx)
  `{[system.windows.messagebox]::show('file already exist')}
Else{
  foreach($ph in $GetMessageOut){$ph+1}`$GetMessageOut = Get-SCEvent -SCSession $session -EventTypes message | Select-Object ActionType,Id,AffectedTenantCount,ExternalLink,StartTime,`enter code here`
Title,EventTYpe,Category,LastUpdatedTime,UrgencyLevel,Endtime,Status,ActionRequiredByDate -ExpandProperty Messages | Export-Excel Z:\Schedule\Messages.xlsx -AutoFilter
}
```

Comment: Is that powershell?

Comment: yes, it is texasbruce

Comment: ...couldnt you add date and time to the file name?

Answer (score 0):

You could add date and time after the file name with this

`Z:\Schedule\Messages$((get-date).tostring("MMddyyyyHHmmss").xlsx`